# when build tensorflow lite python wheel package with tensorflow source code, an error occurred

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I built tensorflow lite python wheel package with tensorflow source code, according to the guidence from official website of tensorflow, https://tensorflow.google.cn/lite/guide/build_cmake_pip?hl=zh-cn. An same error occurred neither I built with source code nor in the docker container, tensorflow/tensorflow:devel, the error is:

compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [//gen/tflite_pip/python3/cmake_build/CMakeFiles/tensorflow-lite.dir/build.make:739: //gen/tflite_pip/python3/cmake_build/CMakeFiles/tensorflow-lite.dir/kernels/conv3d.cc.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/gen/tflite_pip/python3/cmake_build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1217: //gen/tflite_pip/python3/cmake_build/CMakeFiles/tensorflow-lite.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/gen/tflite_pip/python3/cmake_build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1151: //gen/tflite_pip/python3/cmake_build/CMakeFiles/_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/gen/tflite_pip/python3/cmake_build'
make: *** [Makefile:186: _pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper] Error 2

Has anyone ever encountered a similar error? And how to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I got a same error, and looks like in the latest versions of tensorflow lite CMake there is a problem when working with more then 20-30 threads.

So on my end I set BUILD_NUM_JOBS=8 and the CMake of wheel package worked like a charm for me.